# Spring 3.0.5 and Hibernate 3.5.3 - wrong package reference?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am trying to use Spring 3.0.5 with Hibernate 3.5.3-Final and when Spring creates the session, it throws an exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/AssertionFailure

The issue is that the `AssertionFailure` class is actually in the `org.hibernate` package (not `org.hibernate.annotations.common`).  3.0.5 is the latest stable release of Spring and Hibernate 3.5.3-Final was released about a year ago, so it seems odd that it would not be supported.  Is there some workaround for this issue?

Comment: Hibernate 3.5 has confusing inter-relationships between its various JAR files.  Which ones are you using, exactly?

Comment: hibernate-annotations-3.5.3-Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Answer (score 1):

The 3.3.0 version of hibernate-commons-annotations was an erroneous edition. Use 3.2.0.Final.  See http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?89693-AnnotationSessionFactoryBean-needs-MetadataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the hibernate commons annotations jar (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.3.0.ga/)

Comment: Is it ok that the version does not match?

Comment: Yes.  In 3.6 and beyond Hibernate includes the annotations in the main build to avoid this confusion.

Comment: JustinKSU: Even in 3.6.0 the package org.hibernate.annotations.common is not there. Don't know if it's considered obsolete there or in another hibernate module (maybe validator or so)

Comment: Adding the hibernate-commons-annotations seems to have just brought on more missing classes:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider